# Apply CSS class to invalid controls on web form

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to apply a css class to invalid controls on a web form.  I'd like to make it a resusable class.  This is what I have so far:

```
public class Validation
{
    public static void ApplyInvalidClass(Page page, string className)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator bv in page.Validators)
        {
            if (!bv.IsValid)
            {
                Control ctrl = page.FindControl(bv.ControlToValidate);

                if (ctrl != null)
                {
                    if (ctrl is TextBox)
                    {
                        TextBox txt = ctrl as TextBox;
                        txt.CssClass = "invalid";
                    }

                    if (ctrl is DropDownList)
                    {
                        DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
                        ddl.CssClass = "invalid";
                    }

                    if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = ctrl as CheckBox;
                        cb.CssClass = "invalid";
                    }

                    if (ctrl is HtmlGenericControl)
                    {
                        HtmlGenericControl html = ctrl as HtmlGenericControl;
                        html.Attributes.Add("class", className);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is what I call this on a .Net user control, I guess because I'm passing in Page, page.FindControl(bv.ControlToValidate) is always null.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.FindControl` is not recursive, it only searches what is directly in the control collection. It's coming up null because the control you're searching for is nested in the UserControl.

You can see a version of a [recursive FindControl function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987418/asp-net-is-there-a-better-way-to-find-controls-that-are-within-other-controls/1987429#1987429).

Comment: I think that the proper behavior requires resolving using validator.NamingContainer.FindControl(...) instead of page.FindControl(...). There could be several identically named controls in one page.