# Can't find control (ASP.NET, MS TEST)

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing

The following test:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    private TestContext _testContext;
    protected TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return _testContext; }
        set { _testContext = value; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/MyPage.aspx")]
    public void TestMyPage()
    {
        TextBox tb = TestContext.RequestedPage.FindControl("ControlId") as TextBox;
        Assert.IsNotNull(tb);
    }
  }
```

fails, and using the string "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ControlId" as control Id provide a proper control... I know, ASP.NET contains "ClientID" property for web-controls, but is there any possibility to know in advance the control's client Id in the TEST (Under VS 2008)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `ClientID` is what you're after here.  I think your problem is that `FindControl` is not doing what you think it is.

`FindControl` is not recursive.  If your textbox is inside of a `ContentPlaceHolder`, then you need to call `FindControl` on the placeholder, not the `Page`.

Otherwise, I suggest writing a recursive FindControl function that will search the entire control heirarchy.  You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987418/asp-net-is-there-a-better-way-to-find-controls-that-are-within-other-controls/1987429#1987429).