# Loop through controls of a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, controls

I have a user control with 5 simple radiobuttons, I need ot loop through those in code-behind, but I am drawing a huge blank on how to do this. Can someone help please

Comment: Can you post the markup of the user control and how you have defined the radio buttons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
foreach (var ctl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctl is RadioButton)
    {
       // stuff
    }
}
```

Note that this is *not* recursive.  If your radiobuttons are further down in the control container heirarchy, you'll need to write a recursive method to find them.  See my old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987418/asp-net-is-there-a-better-way-to-find-controls-that-are-within-other-controls/1987429#1987429) for an example of a recursive FindControl function.

Comment: YOu cannot use "this.Controls" in a user control

Comment: Correction, you can you "this" but not outside any methods. I am trying to set a property as in (get; set;)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but if you are trying to have a group of related radio buttons, you shouldn't be using individual radio button controls, but a [`RadioButtonList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3se8ewc.aspx) control. This will hold all of the radio buttons in a group and allow you to iterate over them.

Comment: I am using it this way specifically because of a request of the client. I prefer the radiobuttonlist but the require the labels to be on top of the buttons.

Comment: Use CSS to position the labels on top.

Comment: Now I tried using CSS to position them but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late for your case, but this post helped me to discover a solution for your question (which turned out to be my exact question) - specifically how to select a radio button group in a usercontrol in a way that doesn't require code changes if the radio button group changes. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
Protected Function GetRadioButtonGroup(ByVal control As Control, ByVal groupName As String) As RadioButton()
    Dim rbList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of RadioButton)
    If TypeOf control Is RadioButton AndAlso DirectCast(control, RadioButton).GroupName = groupName Then
        rbList.Add(control)
    End If
    If control.HasControls Then
        For Each subcontrol As Control In control.Controls
            rbList.AddRange(GetRadioButtonGroup(subcontrol, groupName))
        Next
    End If
    Return rbList.ToArray
End Function
```

Then all you need to do is this to get the radio buttons in the group (and no other controls):

```
Dim radioButtons As RadioButton() = GetRadioButtonGroup(Me, "MyGroupName")
```

Sorry, but "Use a RadioButtonList" is not a good solution for modifying existing code that someone else wrote, since it will require significant changes to the markup and css. Of course, if I find myself writing my own control, I will use a RadioButtonList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to loop through required user controls, this code also sorts iterations by TabIndex:

```
IEnumerable<RadioButton> rbs = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().OrderBy(ci => ci.TabIndex);
foreach (RadioButton rb in rbs)
{
    // do stuff
}
```